# Likelihood for time-series classification model

Tags: time-series, bayesian

Let's say I have some time series $x_{1..T}$, and my task is to predict the corresponding $y$. But, I want the model to have the ability to use any prefix of $x$ for prediction, not just the full time series. The likelihood model I have in mind is $L(\theta) = \Pi_t \space p_{\theta}(y | x_{1..t})$, but it seems illegitimate to count $y$ multiple times like this. Is this idea OK and, if not, how might I fix it?

Comment: By "corresponding $y$" you mean from the same period as $x$ (i.e., $x_t \to y_t$, $x_{t-1} \to y_{t-1}$, etc.)?

Comment: @Durden No, $y$ is a scalar. I meant corresponding to the given time series.

Comment: In that case, $p_\theta(y|x_{t}, x_{t-1}, \ldots, x_1)$ and $p_\theta(y|x_{t-1}, x_{t-2}, \ldots, x_1)$ are two different models. You probably [average over them](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/70302), but I don't think simply multiplying the likelihoods is valid.